# How To Pass a JRBeanCollectionDataSource to iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans, datasource

I'm currently trying to use jasper to help me create reports. I have the information and data that I want displayed in this method:

```
private void writeToFile(final List<ScenarioLoadModel> sceneLoadModel) throws Exception {
  final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Uma/nft/result.psv"));

  for (final ScenarioLoadModel slm : sceneLoadModel) {
    bw.write(slm.getScenarioId() + PSP + slm.getScenarioId() + PSP + slm.getScenarioConfig().getName() + PSP + slm.getLoad() + PSP + "" + EOL);
    if (!slm.getScenarios().isEmpty()) {
      final int tempCount = slm.getScenarios().get(0).getTemplates().size();
      final int sceneCount = slm.getScenarios().size();
      for (int tempIdx = 0; tempIdx < tempCount; tempIdx++) {
        String id = null;
        int pass = 0;
        int fail = 0;
        final Map<String, BigDecimal> metricMap = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();
        final DefaultStatisticalCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultStatisticalCategoryDataset();
        for (int sceneIdx = 0; sceneIdx < sceneCount; sceneIdx++) {
          final Template temp = slm.getScenarios().get(sceneIdx).getTemplates().get(tempIdx);
          if (temp.isError()) {
            fail++;
          } else {
            pass++;
          }
          if (sceneIdx == 0) {
            id = temp.getId();
          }
          final MetricGroupModel mgm = slm.getScenarios().get(sceneIdx).getMetricGroupModel().get(tempIdx);
          if (mgm != null) {
            for (final MetricModel mm : mgm.getMetricModel()) {
              for (final MetricValue mv : mm.getMetricValue()) {
                dataset.add(mv.getValue(), new BigDecimal(0.0), mv.getType(), id);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        final TemplateConfig tc = TemplateManager.getTemplateConfig(id);

        bw.write(slm.getScenarioId() + PSP);
        bw.write(id + PSP + tc.getName() + PSP + 1 + PSP + pass + "/" + fail);
        for (final Object row : dataset.getRowKeys()) {
          final Number mean = dataset.getValue((String) row, id);
          bw.write(PSP + row + PSP + mean);
        }
        bw.write(EOL);
      }
    }
  }

  bw.close();
}
```

From my understanding I create Beans and then put them all in a Bean Factory, to create my object that will be ready to be passed to iReport.

How can I put all this information into a Bean?  I essentially want the bean to include the scenario/test case and whether or not it passed. (This is for test automation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to read your code to make a a best guess at what columns you would want, but with no context, I have no clue. All the bean is a pojo, with private fields and public getters and setters.

Assuming there is no grouping and essentially each `ScenarioLoadModel` will correspond to one row in the report you would end up with a bean like this:

```
public class ScenariaResults {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String load;

    private int passCount;

    private int failCount;

    public ScenariaResults(String id, String name, String load, int passCount,
            int failCount) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.load = load;
        this.passCount = passCount;
        this.failCount = failCount;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLoad() {
        return load;
    }

    public void setLoad(String load) {
        this.load = load;
    }

    public int getPassCount() {
        return passCount;
    }

    public void setPassCount(int passCount) {
        this.passCount = passCount;
    }

    public int getFailCount() {
        return failCount;
    }

    public void setFailCount(int failCount) {
        this.failCount = failCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ScenariaResults [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", load="
                + load + ", passCount=" + passCount + ", failCount="
                + failCount + "]";
    }

}
```

So basically in the code you have above you build instances of `ScenarioResults` and add them to a list. Once you have the list, all you need to do is create a JRDataSource:

```
List<ScenarioResults> dataBeanList = ...call your method to get the list of results
//create the datasource
JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataBeanList);
```

Now when designing the report in iReport it can be a little tricky to get the fields imported automatically. Basically first add your project with the bean to the classpath in iReports (could just point it to the bin folder or jar file`): Tools -> options -> classpath tab. Now follow these steps to add the fields.

1. Click the following icon: [image: Create datasource]
2. Select the `JavaBean Datasource` tab.
3. Enter the classname of your bean. (ex. `ScenarioResults`)
4. Click `Read attributes`
5. Highlight the fields you want in the report and click `Add Selected Field(s)`.
6. Click `OK`.

Now if you want to test what the report looks like with data, and not just an empty datasource, this is where the Factory comes in. **It is only for testing while using iReport.** You need to create a class that will essentially create a dummy data set for you. It should look something like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ScenarioResultsFactory {

    public static List<ScenarioResults> createBeanCollection() {
        List<ScenarioResults> list = new ArrayList<ScenarioResults>();       
        list.add(new ScenarioResults("1", "test", "load", 10, 5));
        //add as many as you want       
        return list;
    }

}
```

Now you need to create a Datasource pointing to it in iReport.

1. Next to the Datasource dropdown in the toolbar click the icon with the tooltip `Report Datasources.
2. Click `New`.
3. Select `JavaBeans set datasource`. Click `Next`.
4. For name enter `ScenarioResultsFactory`.
5. For the Factory class you need to put the classname including package. So if the class is in the `com` package you should have `com.ScenarioResultsFactory` here.
6. For the static method put `createBeanCollection` if not already there.
7. Check the `Use field description` check box. Click `Test` to make sure it worked.
8. Click `Save`.

Comment: wow this helped me so much. Thank you for your response. This is exactly what I was asking about. I was confused about why all the fields in the Bean Factory were hard coded in all the examples that I have seen. Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: @qwer1234 No problem glad I could help. I didn't think the answer was going to be this long at first, but as I was typing it just kinda happened.

Comment: thanks, haha. yeah it was very simple and straightforward with your explanation.