# Print jrxml report only if the sql used by jrxml has data in it

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to print a report through *Java* only if the sql used by the jrxml has some data in it. In order to do this, I need to hit database twice, First time to check if the sql has any records and second time to print the report. By doing this, its taking twice the time than usual. Is there any way by which I can check if its having the data and print it for the first time itself?

Comment: Yes, you can use [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources), for example. You can collect data and then choose the right way to continue application

Answer (score 0):

**USE JRDataSource**

Well the data returned by sql query can be stored in a Collection say vector, and based on the size of vector you can take your decision. The following is just an approach to implement this idea:-

```
java.util.Vector vector = new java.util.Vector();
vector = getDatabaseRecords(); //function for extracting db records.

if(vector.size() !=0){  //some records 
   //create datasource bean
   JRDataSource bs = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(vector); 
   //compile report 
   JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(url); 
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, bs); } else{ return "no records found"}
```

If you are using iReport, you have to add JavaBean DataSource. For further adding instructions in iReport click [**here**](http://geethapaul.blogspot.in/2007/12/using-javabeans-as-datasource-in.html).

Also you can spare some time to go through [***this*** stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456114/how-to-pass-a-jrbeancollectiondatasource-to-ireport).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the size method of the getPages() attribute of JasperPrint class:

```
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);  
        int noPages = jasperPrint.getPages().size();
        if(noPages > 0) 
        {
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, path + "{name_of_file}.pdf");
        }
        else
        {
            //Do something else...
        }
```